# Accessing ControlTemplate Style In Custom Application.Resources

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, controltemplate

I have created a template style for a button that I would like to call for each album in my project.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomButtonLarge" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="300" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="AlbumContentGrid">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Row="0" source="null" x:Key="albumCover" />
                        <Textblock Grid.Row="1" x:Key="Title" Style="{StaticResources CustomForegroundTitleText}"/>
                        <Textblock Grid.Row="2" x:Key="SubTitle" Style="{StaticResources CustomForegroundSubTitleText}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


</Application.Resources>
```

When I am in the code behind I want to create this button for each album. So if there is 3 albums, I would like to do a for loop...

```
int numberOfButtons= 3;

private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            Style style = App.Current.Resources["CustomButtonLarge"] as Style;

            btn.Style = style;

            StackAlbums.Children.Add(btn);
        }

    }
```

StackAlbums being a stackPanel in the main grid. For some reason I am not getting anything when I run.

But I'm also not sure how to access the "albumCover" Image so that I can change the source to whatever I need it to be in the code and Change the text values of the Title and SubTitle Textblocks.

Comment: Your CustomButtonLarge is no right that you should not `x:Key="SubTitle"` in TextBlock and it is `TextBlock ` not `Textblock `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first, you should fix the Style that the Style has the duplicate property `width` and `Height`.

Then you should make the effect for Background. You should bind it to Grid.

```
                    <Grid x:Name="AlbumContentGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
```

The Grid should be set the `Background` to bind the `Button` background.

And you should remove all the `x:Key`.

If you want to set the Image in code that you should make the data context.

I make a class `Foo` to do it.

```
public class Foo
{
    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string  SubTitle { get; set; }
}
```

And I should set it when adding the button.

```
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int numberOfButtons = 3;


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++)
        {
            var foo = new Foo
            {
                Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png")),
                Title = "title" + i,
                SubTitle = i.ToString()
            };

            Button btn = new Button();
            Style style = Application.Current.Resources["CustomButtonLarge"] as Style;

            btn.Style = style;

            btn.DataContext = foo;

            StackAlbums.Children.Add(btn);
        }
    }
```

The code uses `Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png` and you can change it.

Then I should use bind to bind the data context and all the code for CustomButtonLarge is

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomButtonLarge" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,10,10"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
                    <Grid x:Name="AlbumContentGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Row="0" x:Name="AlbumCover" Source="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" x:Name="SubTitle" Text="{Binding SubTitle}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

I try to run it and clip the screen to you.

[image]

If you want to add the click event that you should add some code.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++)
        {
            var foo = new Foo
            {
                Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png")),
                Title = "title" + i,
                SubTitle = i.ToString()
            };

            Button btn = new Button();
            Style style = Application.Current.Resources["CustomButtonLarge"] as Style;

            btn.Style = style;

            btn.DataContext = foo;

            StackAlbums.Children.Add(btn);

            btn.Click += Button_OnClick; // Make the click
        }
```

And you should write `Button_OnClick` and add break point to know the user click the button.

```
    private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(StackAlbums.Children.Count);
        Debug.WriteLine((StackAlbums.Children[0] as FrameworkElement)?.ActualWidth );
        Debug.WriteLine((StackAlbums.Children[0] as Button)?.Background?.ToString() ?? "");
    }
```

[image]

**Edit**

If you want to add click animation that you should add the code to `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups`.

```
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AlbumContentGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="AlbumContentGrid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Title"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="#aaaaaa" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SubTitle"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="#aaaaaa" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AlbumContentGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="AlbumContentGrid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="AlbumContentGrid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Title"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SubTitle"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AlbumContentGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

You should add the code to AlbumContentGrid like this figure.

[image]

You can see the click animation when you add the code.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time out of your day to do that. Just a quick one though, for some reason the Image is only showing on one of the three buttons. Any ideas why that could be?

Comment: Also, the buttons aren't clickable.

Comment: Okay, the buttons are now all showing the image, but I can't click them...

Comment: For you should add some to get the click event.

Comment: If you think this answer can help you, please click the up vote.

Comment: What I mean is, when I run the app using the custom Style the button doesn't have the default button annimation, it's not reacting to a click. If I was to just place a normal button in the StackAlbums it would have a button animation, normally does if I just create a button and add theme elements to it, but this doesn't...

Comment: In order to make the animation that you should add the visual state see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx